# logics extracting right dates from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

a little problem with dates management in mysql.
I have a table of event dates called `event_dates`:

```
id, date (type date), fk_event
```

and a table called `event  (id, event_name, event_body, status)`

I would like to check if NOW() is minor than the smallest date, greater than the greatest date and if smallest

The first 2 cases are ok, but how can I tell mysql the third option?
That means "`IF NOW()>smallest && NOW()<greatest SELECT the next date bigger than today`".
How could I?

Sure could be easy to accomplish, but honestly, I cannot figure it out after 3 hours of searching and trying.
Thanks you all.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the results you are looking for.

Comment: $date = date(Y-m-day);

 select * from table where date is >'$date'  you can use like this kindly provide the sample code for  well understanding

Comment: Are you using mysql right way? It's relational database. If you want to select something, send query. if query result nothing, but you need data send another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this help you?

Or maybe I misunderstood your problem??

```
SELECT IF( 
NOW() < (select min(date) from event_dates) 
AND NOW() > (select max(date) from event_dates),
(select date from event_dates where date > now() order by date asc limit 1), 
'-1'
);
```